# How do I move a Git branch out into its own repository?

Tags: git, branch, extract

I have a branch that I'd like to move into a separate Git repository, and ideally keep that branch's history in the process.  So far I've been looking at `git filter-branch`, but I can't make out whether it can do what I want to do.

How do I extract a Git branch out into its own repository?

Answer (score 378, accepted):

You can simply push a branch to a new repository. All of its history will go with it. You can then choose whether to delete the branch from the original repository.

e.g.

```
git push url://to/new/repository.git branch-to-move:new-branch-name
```

For a new repository, new-branch-name is typically master.

Creating a new, empty repository can be done with `git init`.

Comment: Just in case anyone's wondering, I substituted the URL with the path to a Git repository directory, and that worked perfectly.

Comment: You can also name the branch name in the new repository:

`git push url://to/new/repository.git branch-to-move:new-branch-name`

Comment: Yves' above comment is correct, otherwise you'll have no master in there and the cloning process will conclude `warning: remote HEAD refers to nonexistent ref, unable to checkout.`. If already at that stage, just go with `git checkout -b branch-to-move` and you're safe or you simply go with `git checkout -b master` to have your master branch :)

Comment: `git checkout -b master` solved my problem it was on the screen `error: src refspec master does not match any.` (only wonder why I didn't see the branch name I was at) Thank you

Comment: Need `git config receive.denyCurrentBranch warn` for new repo because `refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
the work tree to HEAD.`

Comment: @wener another is to create a bare repo with `git --bare init`

Comment: note that this will copy not just the branch and its history, but all the history back to the beginning of the repository, including the history along the branch(es) that the specified branch was branched from

Comment: I had to throw the -f flag in to overwrite the existing history of the remote branch

Comment: This does not copy any tags

Comment: Replying to my own comment to push the tags please use the following command `git push url://to/new/repository.git --tags` kudos

Comment: In case this answer was confusing for you too, here's how I made sense of it in order to make it work: 1) in your terminal, be in the directory that contains the repo and branch you want to make into a new repo; 2) the `url` should be a git url, like git@github.com:brianzelip/groceries.git; 3) `branch-to-move` is the branch of the current repo you want to make into a new repo; 4) `new-branch-name` is the name you want for the new branch in the new repo being created, ie: `master`.

Comment: this command keep all history, without history i need to move only on that branch changes only how ? how i achieve this

Comment: Worked for me only after adding refs:

```git push url://to/new/repository.git branch-to-move:refs/heads/new-branch-name```

Comment: Huge thumbs up, I accidentally pushed a bunch of consecutive commits to the wrong repo and this helped me get back on track!

Comment: Does this command delete the existing branch (in the old repo) after moving ?

Comment: @YoussefN Remove branches doesn't have any meaning. Git branch is just a pointer to specified commit.

Comment: this answer should be updated to have `https://` instead of `url://`. using `url://` gives me `git: 'remote-url' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.`

Comment: Related to this (but I don't think it warrants a new question!) does anyone know if there is a simple way to do this in SourceTree.

Answer (score 21):

This will keep the history of all the branches, but make your copy point to the one branch in particular:

```
git clone -b newbranch CurrentRepo NewRepo
```

This does not 'move' anything, just makes a copy.

Comment: Worth noting that `clone -b` is new. It requires git >= 1.6.5 (released October 2009).

Comment: I had trouble getting this to work, but that was before I saw the message from Charles Bailey.