# How to move a git branch to its own repository (init problems)

Tags: git

I want to move a branch to its own repository. I tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227062/how-do-i-move-a-git-branch-out-into-its-own-repository). I initialize an empty repository:

```
git init --bare
```

I can then push to that repository. However, if I try to clone/fetch/pull it, it does not work because there is no master, and HEAD is not set.

If I run:

```
git remote show origin
```

It does not show any branches. I tried doing

```
git push <new_repo> <branch>:master
```

But this also does not work. It complains that refspec does not match.

Answer (score 0):

So, I solved my own problem. You need to do it in two steps. Firstly, push to a repo initialized with:

```
git init
```

Then push to a remote initialized with:

```
git init --bare
```