# How to slice from large git history but maintain ability to merge/rebase

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

I am currently facing a large git repository (lets call it `upstream`) with commits that reach back more than 10 years. I don't need most of the history from it. Actually it would be enough to slice out a branch from it and transfer it into its own repo and maintain the ability to merge commits from the original `upstream` branch now and then. In my head, this would keep the repo size small.

Depicted: from

```
          D' - E' upstream/release
         /
A - B - C - D - E upstream/dev
```

to

```
D' - E' myrepo/release
```

and be able to `git merge upstream/release` or `git rebase myrepo/master`.

I'm aware that `myrepo/release` would need some artificial init. I already tried a lot with `git checkout --orphan`, `git rebase --onto` etc. but didn't come to a solution. Maybe someone can help with a nice idea!

Thanks,
Jens

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following:

```
git checkout --orphan my_release D'
git add .
git commit -m "Started new history"
```

and then rebasing the entire `upstream/release` branch:

```
git checkout upstream/release
git rebase --onto my_release D' upstream/release
```

and merging:

```
git checkout my_release
git merge upstream/release
```

This results in new commit-IDs, but updating in future might work via rebasing.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40345850/6198494) helped a lot.